# SOAP request with PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I need some help to get started with a SOAP API. I have to implement a API for a vacancy section of a clients website.

I need to implement the SOAP API via PHP.
Do I need to ask for a WSDL file? Or is the included documentation sufficient for calling the api

The documentation describes the following:

**GetAllJob**
*Returns a list of search results. Get requests only.*

Parameters

**&DeveloperKey=**

```
  - Required
```

**&CustomerId=**

```
  - Required, numeric only
```

**&Keywords=**

```
  - Optional, string, must be URL encoded
  - Can accept a single value, or a comma-separated list of values
```

**&Location=**

```
  - Optional, string, must be URL encoded
  - Can accept a single city name, a postal code or a comma-separated city
```

**&Category=**

```
  - Optional, numeric (Category code)
  - Can accept a single value only.
  - If the given value do not match any of category codes, this parameter is ignored. We do not attempt any partial matching
  - Reference the Categories service for a complete list of valid category names and codes
```

**&EducationLevel=**

```
  - Optional, numeric (Education level code)
  - Can accept a single value only.
  - Reference the Education level service for a complete list of valid education level names and codes
```

**Sample Output**
http://piratepad.net/soap-xml-sample-output

Comment: Are you connecting to the SOAP API (i.e. writing the client application), or implementing the SOAP API yourself (i.e. writing the server application)?

Comment: I'm connecting to the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the Zend_Soap_Client, a popular library for connecting to SOAP APIs.

This is a pretty [decent tutorial](http://rekowski.info/home/technical/web/using-zend-soap-client.md) which explains how to use the library. If you are using [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) for dependancy management (which is highly recommended), you can bypass the installation instructions and just install the package **zendframework/zend-soap**.

The basis steps are:

Instantiate a new `Zend_Soap_Client`, passing the WSDL so the client so it is aware of the methods + parameters of the API.

```
$this->soapClient = new Zend_Soap_Client(
    'http://url.to.your.api.com?WSDL'
);
```

Call a method available to you, passing any required parameters, then fetch the result property. So for GetAllJob, its likely to be:

```
$allJobs = $this
    ->soapClient
    ->GetAllJob($parameters)
    ->GetAllJobResult
;
```

Once you're getting some data back, look to integrate the soap client into your wider application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will call to to the API supplier for the wsdl location because in the API doc there's no reference to it. I've to implement it into a Wordpress environment so I think I will stick to the standard SoapClient class in PHP. I will update this post if I got a solution.

Comment: I've got the wsdl file from the supplier. 
They forgot to implement it to the api doc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everything, I've implemented the SoapClient and __soapcall methods from php and now it's working.

The problem was not having the wdsl file. I've got the location of the wdsl and now it's working.